# PHP - Help writing regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to pick up regex using [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/regular-expressions-for-dummies-screencast-series/). However I still haven't got very far and something need's fixing today.

I need a regex that does the following.

```
$html = '...'; // Lots of HTML
$regex = '{absolutely anything}color: #{6 digits - [0-9][a-f][A-F]};{absolutely anything}';
```

I will then use this to force users to have a certain color on their HTML elements.

Would anyone mind converting the $regex variable to actual regex?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) - unless you really mean *{absolutely anything}*

Comment: {absolutely anything} what would be this value, really? HTML? CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "absolutely anything" then... don't add anything else! You can use quantificator and classes for the rest :

```
$regex = '/color: #[a-fA-F0-9]{6};/'
```

[a-fA-F0-9] matches any character between a-f (lowercase), A-F (uppercase) and a digit. {6} means it must has exactly 6 characters.
Don't forget that with PHP's PCRE extension, you need delimiters (/) in this case).

Comment: Slightly shorter: `/color: #[a-f0-9]{6}/i`

Comment: nickf > while this is true, the author didn't mention anything about capturing COLOR or such things. But now, he can pick the solution he wants :-p

Comment: Using a single (literal) white space makes it error prone when there are zero, or more than one spaces. Better do `\s*` or `\s+`, or even `[ ]*` or `[ ]+` when only spaces are allowed and no line breaks.

Comment: Bart Kiers > That's your own representation of the problem. The author wants to capture "color: #{something}", he doesn't necessarily want to capture "color:{space}{space}{space} #{something}" or "color:\n#{something}.

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty close.

```
/color:\s*\#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6};/
```

Comment: Not necessary to escape `#` if you're not using it as a delimiter. Voting on this since it matches 0 to many spaces though and is therefore most flexible ;)

Comment: The only difference between mine and @Vincent's above is I allow for 0 or more spaces between the color: and the #. That may or may not be what you want :)

Answer (score 2):

```
/color: ?#([0-9a-f]{3}){1,2};/i
```

Features:

- Optional whitespace between `color:` and value
- `#rgb` and `#rrggbb` matching

Furthermore, you might want to add a `[^-]` part in order *not* to match `background-color: #...`: `/[^-]color: ?#([0-9a-f]{3}){1,2};/i`. Also, you could use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) if you so desire: `(?<!-)`.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong (which is a distinct possibility here), but I don't *think* PHP supports negative look-behind

Comment: Actually I wouldn't have been sure about this. So thanks, @ircmaxell